# Handling Pop-ups in a Google Chrome Kiosk App

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk, chromebook

Has anyone successfully created a Google Chrome Kiosk App that can handle pop-ups?

My issue: We're trying to use Chromebits for public access catalogs at a public library. Locking down the kiosk app by domain works perfectly to ensure the Chromebits are only used with the catalog. However, an area of our catalog allows users to view their accounts. The account "edit" section is a pop-up, and the kiosk app will not allow it. Any workaround for this? Any other ideas?

I'm using "Kiosk" from the chrome app store.